# Save/Recall Google Maps Options via Ajax & JSON

Tags: json, google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to save a google maps options object via Ajax using JSON to a MySQL database, then extract the data again and parse it back into a Google Maps options object. The basic options I'm trying to save seem to save and recall fine, except for the center property.
I get

> Error: Invalid value for property : [object Object]

Here's a screengrab of a console-dump of the original options object, followed by the same data, as encoded into JSON, saved to the database, extracted from the database again and parsed back into a JS object:

http://mcserver.gold.ac.uk/temp/gmapoptssave.png

(sorry- can't post images here as I'm a newb)

I'm using the json-jquery plugin's jQuery.toJSON function to convert the options object to JSON before sending via ajax. I'm using PHPs encode_json() function before sending the data back to my my JS script.

Can anyone tell me what else I should be doing, or what I should do differently to get recall of the saved options data to work? I've managed to work around the problem with

```
if(savedopts != '') mapopts = jQuery.parseJSON(savedopts);
    // This is a hack- should be able to use the parsed JSON object for center directly
    mapopts['center'] = new google.maps.LatLng(mapopts.center.$a, mapopts.center.ab);
```

but obviously it's not elegant, and I'd like to be able to save other kinds of options data too, in the future.

Any tips much appreciated,

Cheers,

a|x

Comment: Make an edit to your question that includes the actual JSON payloads; it will make it easier to find any problems and give you a hand.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for getting back to me. Here's the raw JSON string returned to my JS scripts from the server:

`{"center":{"$a":64.086051097464,"ab":-21.786269090476935},"zoom":12,"mapTypeId":"hybrid","mapTypeControl":true,"zoomControl":true,"panControl":true,"streetViewControl":false,"labels":true}`.

Does this help track down the issue?

Comment: My suspicion is that the saved/recalled center value is a generic JavaScript object, whereas the original center object is an instance of a Google Maps-API-specific object. I don't know how to get around this though. Maybe my 'hack' is the only way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Not all properties of the MapOptions type are directly serializable. In particular, the LatLng object is known to have this restriction (which is the type of the "center" property). Instead, you'll need to manually serialize this value using either the LatLng.toString() or LatLng.toUrlValue() methods and then recreate the LatLng object when retrieving the value from the database.

### Storing

```
var optsToSave = mapopts;
optsToSave.center = mapopts.center.toUrlValue();
// store optsToSave in database
```

### Retreiving

```
var mapopts = jQuery.parseJSON(savedopts);
mapopts.center = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(mapopts.center.substring(0, mapopts.center.indexOf(','))),
    parseFloat(mapopts.center.substring(mapopts.center.indexOf(',') + 1)));
```

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks very much for that! I'll give it a go.
I guess it's because they're object-types that have methods other than those of generic JavaScript objects. Are any of the other other properties similar, off the top of your head?

Thanks again,

a|x

Comment: I've not tested all of them, but LatLng is the one that most often people encounter.